# Manhwa about a saint escaping from the church with the help of the male lead

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhwa.

The female lead is a white-haired saint. She can see people's futures by touching them. She is stuck in a church and they plan to sacrifice her as God's bride. The male lead comes and saves her and marries her. They then go to another land out of the church's reach.

So can anyone tell me the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this ***[When Fate Finds Us](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/when-fate-finds-us)***...?

> As a prophetess, Noemi can see the futures of those she touches. Yet sadly, as the wife of a god, she sees only death in her own fateful future. But then, a sudden kiss with an unruly merchant brings a vision of life. Could he be Noemi's key to survival? Or will she be unable to escape her destiny?
>
> [image: Promotional art for "When Fate Finds Us."]

The female lead is a white-haired saint who can see the futures of those she touches. People visit a church to see her to have their fortunes told, but she has visions of being sacrificed as the "wife of God" by the priests she serves.

The male lead is man who'd previously had his fortune told by her. He returns to see her again and proposes that he take her to another country and marry her in order to free her from her servitude.